# HTTP Status 404 --- Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I run the code on tomcat 8.0.39 and it first shows the login.jsp  When I fill the name and password and hit submit it returns the 404 error:login.jsp image
[HTTP Status 404 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I11Ag.png)

My code follows:

web.xml

```
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>To do List</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package com.ezmsip;

import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/login.do")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));

    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hola desde una JSP</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/login.do" method="post">
Nombre: <input type="text" name="name" /> Password: <input type="password"      name="password" /> <input type="submit" value="Log-in" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Bienvenido!</title>
</head>
<body>
Bienvenido!  ${name}
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't complain about login.jsp. It complains about `/login.do`. Did you deploy this app as the root web app in tomecat? Otherwise, it's under a context path, and you need your action to be something like `/myWebApp/login.do`.

In any case, the right thing to do is to prepend the context path:

```
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login.do"
```

or, using the JSTL:

```
action="<c:url value='/login.do'/>"
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I added the page context and it worked.